# Google plus integration not working with Php

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I am working on google plus integration with php,but whenever i hit "mydomainname.com/example.php" then i am getting following error_get_last

> "400. That’s an error.Error: redirect_uri_mismatch",

In google console's Authorized redirect URIs section,i put following url 
myurl/google-plus/example.php

Here is my example.php file code,Where i am wrong ?

```
<?php
/* Require library */
require_once 'class.googleplus.php';
/* Configuration Values */
$config['consumer_key'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$config['consumer_secret']   = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['callbackUrl']  = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '?verify';
$GooglePlus = new GooglePlusPHP($config);
/* Verification phase */
if (!isset($_SESSION['googlePlusOAuth']) && isset($_GET['verify']) && isset($_GET['code'])):
    try {
        unset($_SESSION['googlePlusOAuth']);
        $accessToken = $GooglePlus->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
        $GooglePlus->setOAuthToken($accessToken->access_token, false);
        $_SESSION['googlePlusOAuth'] = $accessToken;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
        exit;
    }
    header('Location: example.php');
    exit;
endif;
/* No token, and no ?verify . Redirect to auth. */
if (!isset($_SESSION['googlePlusOAuth'])):
    header('Location: ' . $GooglePlus->getAuthorizationUrl() );
endif;
/* Set Access Token */
$GooglePlus->setOAuthToken($_SESSION['googlePlusOAuth']['access_token']);
if (!$GooglePlus->testAuth())
    die('Your token probably expired, or was not valid. Clear the session and try again.');

/* Profile */
$profile = $GooglePlus->getMyProfile();
/* My Activities */
$activities = $GooglePlus->getMyActivities();
/* People Search */
if (isset($_GET['search'])):
    if (isset($_GET['search_pagetoken'])):
        $search_pagetoken = $_GET['search_pagetoken'];
    else:
        $search_pagetoken = null;
    endif;
    $search_results = $GooglePlus->searchPeople($_GET['search'], $search_pagetoken);
endif;
/* Load Profile, override $activities */
if (isset($_GET['profile_id'])):
    $profile_id = $_GET['profile_id'];
    if (!is_numeric($profile_id)): continue; endif;

    $activities = $GooglePlus->getPublicActivities($profile_id);

    $user_profile = $GooglePlus->getUserProfile($profile_id);
endif;
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Google+</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Google+ Example Script</h1>

<h2>$profile</h2>
<pre><?php var_dump($profile); ?></pre>
<hr />

<h2>$search_results</h2>
<p>Set $_GET['search'] to view results.</p>
<pre><?php var_dump($search_results); ?></pre>
<hr />

<h2>$user_profile</h2>
<p>Set $_GET['profile_id'] to view results.</p>
<pre><?php var_dump($user_profile); ?></pre>
<hr />

<h2>$activities</h2>
<pre><?php var_dump($activities); ?></pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In case you don't know, Google plus will ends its services in april 2019.

Comment: Google will Shut down Google+ for consumer (personal) accounts on April 2, 2019. https://support.google.com/plus/answer/9195133

Comment: The Google+ api shuts down March 7th, 2019

Answer (score 2):

> redirect_uri_mismatch

Means that the Redirect uri that you have entered in the Google developer console for your project is not the same as the redirect URI that your code is using.  If you check the page there should be a link where it tells you exactly where its getting the call from you should simply need to add that link

**API SHUTDOWN WARNING**

That being said you should be aware that the api you are using is going to be shut down in the next few weeks fixing this is probably a waste of time.   Check the top of the page at [people.search](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/search)

[image]